# Meaning of "a certain air of"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "a certain air of" mean? I met it in the Chapter 3 of "A Study in Scarlet" by sir A. C. Doyle:

> He was a man with some amount of self-importance and **a certain air of** command.

Comment: A certain dictionary definition is relevant here: [*(specific but not explicitly named or stated)*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/certain)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've just re-looked at this from 2016, as someone up-voted my answer.  I remain convinced that the OP's example is OED sense 7, which your quoted dictionary reference does not seemto cover. I think your's is more in line with sense 1. "A certain person always asks the same question..." which refers to a known specific person. However if I say "In order to make it work one would need a certain amount of help" - "certain" does not refer to anything specific - an unknown and/or unspecified amount. That seems to me more in line with the Conan Doyle example. Anyway - happy new year!

Comment: You're quite right. Obviously I don't specifically remember posting my link - but in my defence, I did only say it was a "relevant" definition. Anyway, apparently I never saw *your* answer, which was posted a bit later. So (belated) happy new year to you too, and please accept my *seriously* belated upvote! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to exude an impression of command. You know, some people just give off a feeling  that they are a certain way. It is not always a tangible thing that you can point to, it is often a mixture of obvious confidence and how they present themselves, and sometimes you pick up subconscious clues from how others around that person are deferring to them. But you just get a feeling that this person is a certain way - in this case of being a leader.

The flip side to that is the phrase "putting on airs" which is a derogatory term that a person is acting superior when they are not.

Answer (score 4):

The word ***certain*** is being used in a frequently encountered sense, aptly described by the OED as its meaning 7d.

I looked at the link in @Fumble Fingers comment, but felt instinctively that the inclusion of *specific* as part of the definition was not entirely correct. I think the OED is right in not **not including any implication of *specific***.

> **7d. Of positive yet restricted (or of positive even if restricted) quantity, amount, or degree; of some extent at least.**
>
> a1538   T. Starkey Dial. Pole & Lupset (1989) 9   Ther ys a certyn
>   equyte & justyce among al natyonys & pepul.
>
> 1711   J. Addison Spectator No. 106. ¶6   His Virtues..are as it were
>   tinged by a certain Extravagance.
>
> 1763   F. Brooke Hist. Lady Julia Mandeville I. 44   A prodigious
>   passion for people of a certain rank, a phrase of which she is
>   peculiarly fond.
>
> 1763   F. Brooke Hist. Lady Julia Mandeville I. 63,   I knew her rage
>   for title, tinsel, and ‘people of a certain rank’.
>
> 1810   G. Rose Diaries (1860) II. 476   Mr. Perceval..found a certain
>   improvement in him.
>
> 1845   S. Austin tr. L. von Ranke Hist. Reformation in Germany III.
>   131   He kept up a certain degree of intercourse..with the
>   Gonfaloniere Capponi.
>
> 1860   J. Tyndall Glaciers of Alps i. 123   The ice is disintegrated
>   to a certain depth.
>
> 1875   W. S. Jevons Money (1878) 117   The bank makes a certain profit
>   out of the business.

**A synonymous expression to *a certain air of*, therefore might be *to some extent an air of*.**

Comment: Incidentally, according to NGrams, the third most common word in the sequence **a certain * of** is ***degree*** (behind ***amount*** and ***number***), which chimes with the ***to some extent*** paraphrasing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I often express scepticism about NGrams, it would be the action of a hypocrite to accept their endorsement for something I've said. But I'm glad that you agree. Thanks.