# Looking for a word to describe a feeling

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes the shared emotional aura that’s around a group of people.

For example, if you were to hang out with friends, even though you might not feel great, the combined aura of everybody being glad to see each other makes them happier, even if it’s only while they are there.

Another example would be the feeling of authority when entering the office of a person of higher power.

Comment: The first word you are seeking, I suggest would be *convivial*, or *conviviality*. *The conviviality of the evening lifted John's spirits*. Could your second word be *trepidation*. *With some trepidation, Seamus entered the Head Master's study*. .

Comment: I think your first and second examples aren't parallel.  In the first, you all have the same feeling.  In the second, you have a different feeling than the higher power does.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [**atmosphere**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/atmosphere)

> *noun* a surrounding or pervading mood, environment, or influence

---

> "The *atmosphere* of the happy gathering made me forget my worries, if only for the moment."
>
> "The tense *atmosphere* was evident when our boss entered the conference room to discuss our recent performance"

Answer (score 2):

If a phrase is acceptable, you may find the figurative expression ***in the air*** useful.

TFD:

> **[in the air](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+air)**
>   *Fig*. everywhere; all about.
>
> There is such a feeling of joy in the air.
>   We felt a sense of tension in the air.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to the others that came before mine: ***air*** —
specifically, the idiom “air of”:

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/air):
>
> - outward appearance of a thing <an *air* of luxury>
>
>   a surrounding or pervading influence :
>     atmosphere <an *air* of mystery>
>
>   the look, appearance, or bearing of a person
>     especially as expressive of some personal quality or emotion : demeanor
>     <an *air* of dignity>
>
>   an artificial or affected manner <put on *airs*>
>
> [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/air):
>
>   **manner or appearance:**
>   Examples:
>     She has an air of confidence about her.
>
>     He had a slight air of menace which I found unsettling.
>
>     I just assumed he owned the place – he had a proprietary air about him.
>
>     The company operates out of modern offices and expensive hotel suites
>       to create an air of respectability.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries – English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/air):
>
>   An impression of a quality or manner given by someone or something.
>     ‘she answered with a faint air of boredom’
>
>     ‘he leaned over with a confidential air’
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/air_1):
>
>   - a feeling or attitude that someone has
>       
>       *She spoke with her usual air of authority.*
>
>     the feeling that a place or situation gives you
>       
>       *The overgrown lawn gave the house a neglected air.
>
>       There was an air of gloom about the whole trial.*

Here’s an example of usage “in the wild” that seems to match your example:

> There is an **air of happiness and contentment** at Tuningi
>   which soon makes one forget the stresses of life.  …
>                   — [Review of Tuningi Safari Lodge – TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g471868-d507256-r194194397-Tuningi_Safari_Lodge-Madikwe_Game_Reserve_North_West_Province.html)

The verb ***project*** goes well with the phrase ***an air of***:

> Dresow knew he couldn’t look unsure of himself as he walked in. 
>   You need to “just walk in like you know what you’re doing
>   even if you don’t,” he says. 
>   Most importantly, he needed to **project an air of authority**,
>   conviction, and certainty.  …
>                   — [How To Enter A Room Like A Boss](http://mobile.businessinsider.com/how-to-enter-a-room-like-a-boss-2014-5), [Business Insider](http://mobile.businessinsider.com)

More examples from recent headlines:

> Paris climate change talks yield first draft amid **air of optimism**
>                   — [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2015/dec/05/paris-climate-change-talks-draft-french-summit)

> There’s an **air of menace** about this campaign
>                   — [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/theres-an-air-of-menace-about-this-campaign/2016/03/17/8cb5961a-ec70-11e5-a6f3-21ccdbc5f74e_story.html?utm_term=.fbc715e44c6b)

(I bolded words in the above examples for emphasis.)

Related: [Meaning of “a certain air of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/301606/26083).

Answer (score 0):

The psychological term **groupthink** is attributed to William Whyte from a 1952 *Fortune* magazine article. This is based primarily on work by Carl Jung in group dynamics and by the next generation of psychoanalysts.

Answer (score 0):

How about **community**, **fellowship**, or **camaraderie**?

From Merriam-Webster:

> [**community**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/community):
>   social activity : fellowship
>
> [**fellowship**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fellowship):
>   community of interest, activity, feeling, or experience; a company of
>   equals or friends : association; the quality or state of being
>   comradely
>
> [**comaraderie**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/camaraderie):
>   feeling of good friendship among the people in a group

Of these, I think **comaraderie** may be closest to the word you are seeking, but all three work. You feel a sense of **community**, a sense of **fellowship**, a sense of **comaraderie**.

Answer (score 0):

For Definition #1, you could use *ambience, atmosphere, vibe, good vibe, or positive vibe*.  The three versions of *vibe* could be used in the plural, for example,

> The positive vibes at Sara's house last night reminded me of old times.

For Definition #2, you feel *awe* (noun), or you feel *awed* or *cowed* (adj.).